# Why are std[in,out] not line buffered even when connected to terminal?

Tags: c, unix, io, stdin

According to [unix advanced programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543):

```
We can see that the default for this system is to have standard input and standard
output line buffered when they’re connected to a terminal.
```

From this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long buffer_size(FILE *fp)
{
    return (fp->_IO_buf_end - fp->_IO_buf_base);
}

int is_linebf(FILE *fp)
{
    return (fp->_flags & _IOLBF);
}

int is_unbf(FILE *fp)
{
    return (fp->_flags & _IONBF);
}

void stream(const char *name, FILE *fp)
{
    printf("stream = %s, ", name);
    if (is_unbf(fp))
    {
        printf("unbuffered");
    }
    else if (is_linebf(fp))
    {
        printf("line buffered");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("fully buffered");
    }
    printf(", buffer size = %ld\n", buffer_size(fp));
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fputs("enter any character: ", stdout);
    if (getchar() == EOF)
    {
        perror("getchar error");
    }
    fputs("one line to standard error\n", stderr);

    stream("stdin", stdin);
    stream("stdout", stdout);
    stream("stderr", stderr);

    if ((fp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen error");
    }
    if (fgetc(fp) == EOF)
    {
        perror("fgetc error");
    }
    stream("/etc/passwd", fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

If I run it:

```
$ ./a.out
enter any character: a
one line to standard error
stream = stdin, fully buffered, buffer size = 1024
stream = stdout, fully buffered, buffer size = 1024
stream = stderr, unbuffered, buffer size = 1
stream = /etc/passwd, fully buffered, buffer size = 4096
```

Even having the std[in,out] connected to `tty`, they are *fully buffered* instead of being *line buffered*. So is the book wrong or I am missing something?

`uname -a`:

```
Linux 5.8.0-44-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 9 06:29:41 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The example in the book uses OS-specific macros for 4 OSes (solaris,openBSD,linux and macos), so my OS is among them as well.

EDIT:
In  *my* machine, implementation of macros and FILE struct:

*<stdio.h>*

```
/* The possibilities for the third argument to `setvbuf'.  */
#define _IOFBF 0        /* Fully buffered.  */
#define _IOLBF 1        /* Line buffered.  */
#define _IONBF 2        /* No buffering.  */
```

*<struct_FILE.h>*

```
struct _IO_FILE
{
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  char *_IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char *_IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char *_IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char *_IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char *_IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char *_IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char *_IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char *_IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */

  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};

struct _IO_FILE_complete
{
  struct _IO_FILE _file;
#endif
  __off64_t _offset;
  /* Wide character stream stuff.  */
  struct _IO_codecvt *_codecvt;
  struct _IO_wide_data *_wide_data;
  struct _IO_FILE *_freeres_list;
  void *_freeres_buf;
  size_t __pad5;
  int _mode;
  /* Make sure we don't get into trouble again.  */
  char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
};
```

`FILE` is simply `typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE`

Comment: `default for this system` -- are you running the same system as found in the book? Do you expect *your* system to be line buffered by default?

Comment: @Oka see edits, linux (my os) uses the right implementation of FILE structure as the book does as well.

Comment: In your implementation, are `_IONBUF`, etc. single bits?  I can see a reasonable implementation using multiple bits for those, which would make your helper functions suspect.

Comment: @WilliamPursell these macros _IO* are defined in `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Why do you even expect something like `return (fp->_IO_buf_end - fp->_IO_buf_base)` to work in general?  There is no "standard" `FILE` structure, and on some systems you can't even access its members.

Comment: @EricPostpischil see edits

Comment: @AndrewHenle see edits

Answer (score 1):

Previous point:

As [stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547333/why-are-stdin-out-not-line-buffered-even-when-connected-to-terminal/66547666#comment117642430_66547333), your helper functions may not accurately portray the real default state of your system file buffering.

---

That said, file buffering is implementation defined, from C11 N1570:

**§7.21.3**

> 3 - [...]
> *When a stream is fully buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment. **Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined**, and may be affected via the setbuf and setvbuf functions.*

> 7 - *At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly -- standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). **As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device**.*

My emphasis.

From my personal experience in Linux and MacOS, for what it's worth, `stdin` and `stdout` are line-buffered when associated with a terminal and fully-buffered otherwise, whereas `stderr` is unbuffered, so this is consistent with the behavior described in the book, unlike, apparently, in your particular case, but again, this is implementation defined.

I wouldn't say the book is wrong, but *default behavior* can definitely be interpreted as this being the norm and always true for the aforementioned systems.

Comment: While the C standard says support is implementation-defined, it seems unlikely that Linux would not support them. This is not likely the explanation for OP’s observations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I've never encontered one that doesn't, anyway, the point is that is doesn't have to.